# Returning error JSON response in case of CustomException instead of regular json response mapped to bean in Sping boot Restful ws

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a Restful webservice using Spring boot. The response is a bean `EmployeeResponseData` which is converted to json by spring. As per business the web service should return the employee details when the input employee id is a match else a json response with error should be returned as below

```
{"Error ": "Employee not not found for empId "+ **empId** }
```

As of now i am getting the proper json response as per bean `EmployeeResponseData` if the input empId is a match. But i am getting blank if the empId did not match.

How can i return JSON with the desired error in case of custom Exception , without having to form json and return instead of using beans as return object as it is automatically converted to jSON by Spring.

Below is the code.

**Beans**

EmployeeRequestData

```
package com.beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmployeeRequestData {
    private int EmpoyeeId;

    public int getEmpoyeeId() {
        return EmpoyeeId;
    }

    public void setEmpoyeeId(int empoyeeId) {
        EmpoyeeId = empoyeeId;
    }


}
```

EmployeeResponseData

```
package com.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmployeeResponseData {

    private int employeeId;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private ArrayList<String> skills; 

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }
    public void setSkills(ArrayList<String> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }   
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.beans.EmployeeResponseData;
import com.service.ServiceRequest;

@RestController
public class WebServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;

    @RequestMapping(value="restws/getEmpDetails/{empId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    //@ResponseBody   // not required since using @RestController
    public EmployeeResponseData getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("empId") int empId) {
        return serviceRequest.getEmployeeDetails(empId);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.beans.EmployeeResponseData;
import com.exception.EmployeeNotFoundException;

@Service
public class ServiceRequest {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceRequest.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeResponseData employeeResponseData;

    public EmployeeResponseData getEmployeeDetails(int empId) {

             ArrayList<String> employeeSkills = (ArrayList<String>) Stream.of("Core Java"
                    ,"Restful web services"
                    ,"Spring Boot"
                    ,"PLSQL").collect(Collectors.toList());

            employeeResponseData.setEmployeeId(empId);
            employeeResponseData.setName("Priyanjan Kumar");
            employeeResponseData.setDepartment("ENGNE");
            employeeResponseData.setSkills(employeeSkills);
        }else {
            try {
                throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(empId);
            } catch (EmployeeNotFoundException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Employee data not found for empId :"+empId);
            }
        }
        return employeeResponseData;
    }
}
```

**Custom Exception**

```
package com.exception;

public class EmployeeNotFoundException extends Exception{

    private String message = "Employee not found";

    public EmployeeNotFoundException() {
        // super(message); it takes only static variable
    }

    public EmployeeNotFoundException(int empId) {
        message = message+" for Employee : "+ Integer.toString(empId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @ControllerAdvice annotation to handle various types of exceptions thrown in the application.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Below is a sample code of how it looks:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleEntityNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        return ResponseUtil.buildErrorResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleGenericException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        return ResponseUtil.buildErrorResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

You can write a method to build error messages as per you requirement.

Also, you need to add throws Exception declaration in your controller like this:

```
public EmployeeResponseData getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("empId") int empId) throws Exception {
    return serviceRequest.getEmployeeDetails(empId);
}
```

You might need to re-write your service class logic to get data from some resource or DB and based on the result, you can build bean response in success case or throw exception accordingly.

```
public EmployeeResponseData getEmployeeDetails(int empId) {

     // Get data from resource/DB based on empId
     EmployeeResponseData employeeResponseData = new EmployeeResponseData();
     if (data != null) {
         ArrayList<String> employeeSkills = (ArrayList<String>) Stream.of("Core Java"
                ,"Restful web services"
                ,"Spring Boot"
                ,"PLSQL").collect(Collectors.toList());

        employeeResponseData.setEmployeeId(empId);
        employeeResponseData.setName("Priyanjan Kumar");
        employeeResponseData.setDepartment("ENGNE");
        employeeResponseData.setSkills(employeeSkills);
    } else {
           throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(empId);
        }
    }
    return employeeResponseData;
}
```

Comment: i am getting compilation Error saying ResponseUtil cannot be resolved in class RestExceptionHandler . Do i have to add any extra dependency for this?

Comment: Its an custom class which can be written by you to handle various types of response like success response and error response. I just gave an example.

Answer (score 1):

First, write a POJO class named ApiErrorReponse.java

```
public class ApiErrorResponse{
    private final String error;
    //Any addtional info you might later want to add to it
    public ApiErrorResponse(String error){
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getError(){
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, change the endpoint to.

```
@RequestMapping(value="restws/getEmpDetails/{empId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("empId") int empId) {
    EmployeeResponseData data = serviceRequest.getEmployeeDetails(empId);

    if(data != null){
        return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponseData>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    ApiErrorResponse errorReponseDto = new ApiErrorResponse("Employee not not found for empId "+ empId);
    return  new ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse>(errorReponseDto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

You might want to improve the basics, your service class is poorly written and may not work all the times.

**EDIT**

So as per your comment, what you can do is throw exception(s) in your service class and in your controller, catch those exceptions and return the exception message as error response.

```
@RequestMapping(value="restws/getEmpDetails/{empId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("empId") int empId) {

    try{
        EmployeeResponseData data = serviceRequest.getEmployeeDetails(empId);
        return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponseData>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ApiErrorResponse errorReponseDto = new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getMessage());
        return  new ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse>(errorReponseDto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is almost what i want. But instead of setting the error in the controller i want to set the error in the Service class , So if i set the error message in the service class , then how do i get that object of ApiErrorResponse which has the error message in the controller. because there are different error cases , and coding for all of it in controller is not a good idea. Also the data might not be null but only we can't send it in response as the requester doesn't have priviledge to see the data.  My service class i have hardcoded to give just a basic idea.